# Using a Power Automate flow, how do I convert JSON array to a delimited string?

Tags: power-automate

In Power Automate I am calling an API which returns this JSON:

```
    {
   "status":"200",
   "Suburbs":[
      {
         "ID":"1000",
         "Name":"CONCORD WEST",
         "Postcode":"2138"
      },
      {
         "ID":"1001",
         "Name":"LIBERTY GROVE",
         "Postcode":"2138"
      },
      {
         "ID":"1002",
         "Name":"RHODES",
         "Postcode":"2138"
      },
      {
         "ID":"3891",
         "Name":"UHRS POINT",
         "Postcode":"2138"
      },
      {
         "ID":"1003",
         "Name":"YARALLA",
         "Postcode":"2138"
      }
   ]
}
```

Using PA actions, how do I convert this JSON to a String variable that looks like this?:
"CONCORD WEST, LIBERTY GROVE, RHODES, UHRS POINT, YARALLA"

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do this. I prefer not to use complex code-style expressions in Power Automate flows as I think they are hard to understand and hard to maintain so used standard PA actions where I could.

I parsed the JSON, then used "Select" to pick out the suburb names, then used concat() within a "for each" loop through the Suburbs array. I think that Compose could probably be used in the place of the concat() but stopped investigating once I'd found this solution.

[image: Parse JSON, select then for each]